# Can't add variable to class Combination with Prestashop overrides (works with class Product)

Tags: php, variables, overriding, prestashop-1.7

The following `override/classes/Product.php` creates a new variable `$foobar` to the Product class :

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
class Product extends ProductCore
{
    public $foobar;
}
```

When I create a `new Product()`, I can see this new variable.

Now I want to do the same with the Combination class, so I create a similar `override/classes/Combination.php` :

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
class Combination extends CombinationCore
{
    public $foobar;
}
```

However when I create a `new Combination()`, this new field doesn't exist.

What am I missing ?

FWIW, I'm using PS 1.7.6.1.

### Update

Actually it seems `override/classes/Combination.php` is never called : I added a faulty line which should trigger an exception (and it does in `override/classes/Product.php`), but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I deleted `/cache/class_index.php` as advised [in the documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors), but there was still a `/var/cache/dev/class_index.php` which was preventing my modifications to take effect.

Deleting it solved the issue.

Note there is a similar file under `/var/cache/prod/`, which may need to be deleted should a similar situation occur in a production environment.